# How is the performance of Postgres / TimescaleDB unique composite keys?

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

To make it short:

I have a TimescaleDB table with multiple rows:

- from
- to
- code
- point
- ...

There are a few more rows.
I need to keep the rows unique so that the combination of the above rows (from, to, code, point) is unique. The rows can have multiple identical entries, but the combination must be unique.

How would that affect the performance? There would be relative many insertions (a few hundred insertions per minute).

---

EDIT:

The project is still relatively new so we can make changes to the database. There are alternatives that I can consider. I also do not know if there will only be a few hundred insertions per minute or if the volume will scale with time. I know the question leaves space for debates and I am grateful for every answer, but I asked how composite keys affect performance so I can make an informed decision.

Comment: What does it matter what the performance profile is? If they need to be unique then you need a unique constraint.

Comment: A few hundred insertions per minute is not a lot, not even it was a few hundred insertions per second.

Comment: of course it matters. There are available alternatives like an additional row with a hash consisting of those above values for example. The question wasn't if it makes sense, the question was how much composite keys affect performance.

Comment: Have you tested it? If so what did you analysis reveal? Does the performance meet SLA (Service Level Agreements). If you have not tested it, why no? That is truly the only way to make an informed decision.